# useNavigate - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS in frontend and NodeJS in backend and I'm trying to redirect with navigate function but I'm getting the error. What should I do exactly? Where am I missing? How can I redirect if the registration form is successful?

**My action:**

```
export const signup = (formData,navigation) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await API.signUp(formData)
        dispatch({type:AUTH,payload:data})
        let navigate = useNavigate();
        navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type:SIGNUP_FAIL,payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
    }
}
```

**My component:**

```
const signUpForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(!login){
        dispatch(signup(form,navigation))
    }
}
```

Comment: is useNavigate a custom hook?

Comment: useNavigate will be the syntax for navigating in a component. There will be a different syntax for navigating outside a component. Look at the docs for whatever navigator you're using.

Answer (score 5):

You need to move the hook outside of the function:

```
const signUpForm = (e) => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    e.preventDefault()
    if(!login){
        dispatch(signup(form,navigation,navigate))
    }
}
```

and:

```
export const signup = (formData,navigation,navigate) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await API.signUp(formData)
        dispatch({type:AUTH,payload:data})
        navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type:SIGNUP_FAIL,payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message
    })
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: And in what place is it called signUpForm?

Comment: `<Form className='align-content-center mt-3' onSubmit={signUpForm}> ... </Form>` . in the same component

Comment: the point is that onSubmit is a function and you cannot use hooks in it. use the hook in the component then pass it to the function

Comment: i'm so beginner to do that you say. i don't quite understand how to use

Comment: Where the Form component is located, at the beginning of the component write let navigate = useNavigate();

Comment: If i do as you say, even if there is an error in the form, it will redirect. i want it to redirect if the form registration is successful.

Comment: Just pass the navigate variable as onSubmit = {() => signUpForm (navigate)} and it should work as it should

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Move your React Hook (useNavigate, useEffect, useState, etc) to the root of your function component, or else it's considered to be Breaking Rules of Hooks (see below).

### Why:

Complementing @hindus post, and according to the official React Documentation [Rules of Hooks](https://Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called%20inside%20the%20body%20of%20a%20function%20component.), `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component`.

### Code Review

#### **Hard Fail:**

```js
export const SomeView = (props: IDefaultProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate(ErrorPages.Unauthorized, { replace: true });
  });

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

#### **Success (thanks @Himdus):**

```js
export const SomeView = (props: IDefaultProps) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // move to the root (outside any component function)

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(ErrorPages.Unauthorized, { replace: true });
  });

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

### About the Rules:

[Breaking Rules of Hooks](https://Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called%20inside%20the%20body%20of%20a%20function%20component.), stand:

> Functions whose names start with use are called Hooks in React.
>
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, > > always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early > returns. You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:
>
> ✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
>
> ✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.